# Grid View shows in front of tool bar not below

Tags: java, android

I just Create a simple an xml file with a tool bar and grid view, the problem is the grid view show infornt of tool bar not below the tool bar like this
[Grid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjIYV.png)

and this is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/menuGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have diferent options

- Change your FrameLayout for LinearLayout (orientation vertical)
- Change your FrameLayout for RelativeLayout and use 'layout_below'

I recommend you to use LinearLayout

Examples:

**LinearLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/menuGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**RelativeLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/menuGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

FrameLayout is designed to display a single item.

Generally FrameLayout should be used to hold single child view.

You can however add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout.

So if you want to continue with FrameLayout then you can add LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as child inside FrameLayout as given below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/menuGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#d2d2d2"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` and set the orientation to vertical :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/menuGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#d2d2d2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout >
```